# Keeping PostgreSQL data in docker and OSX

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have an OSX host with a postgreSQL database (actually experimenting with it for Redmine). All I want is to be able to keep data after I destroy a container so I'll be safe and I can re-deploy my repository fast.

If I try to add a local Volume in Kitematic, the container fails to start with error:

```
initdb: could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_xlog/archive_status":  Permission denied
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
creating subdirectories ...
```

I've tried to chmod 777 -R the local folder but same result. 
Does anyone have any solution for this or anything else to suggest on saving/keeping data from postgreSQL and docker ?

Answer (score 1):

OSX means boot2docker, and that Linux VM will:

- only mount /Users (from your host)
- only persists data from `/var/lib/docker` and `/var/lib/boot2docker`

So, `/var/lib/postgresql` is either:

- not visible from  the VM (not mounted)
- not writable or persisted from within the VM

The command [`docker volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) should enable you to create a volume in the right path.
See:

- "[Managed data in container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/)"
- [`docker compose` volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver)

Comment: Indeed but do you have any solution to suggest for keeping data ? Except building another vm (e.g. Vagrant) and install docker inside ?

Comment: I actually added a volume but postgres fails to start with the message above. Does it make sense ? The issue happens If I enter the Volumes tab in Kitematic and try to map with a local drive.

Comment: @ChrisV. forget Kitematic for now. Try it with a docker-compose.yml file.